# C++ type-erasing generic functor objects

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-erasure

I have a bunch of those classes that implement a generic call operator:

```cpp
template<typename T = char>
struct match {

    template<initer_of_type<T> IterT>
    constexpr auto operator()(IterT iter) const -> std::optional<decltype(iter)> {
        // ... function body
    }
    // ... some members
}
// ... more similar structs
```

in a class template, where the operator itself is also a template.
NOTE: I'm using here a concept that I made to accept any input iterator that returns the specific value type:

```cpp
template<typename IterT, typename T>
concept initer_of_type =
    std::input_iterator<IterT>
    && std::is_same_v<typename IterT::value_type, T>;
```

That way I can use the algorithm on any iterable `T`s container...

I'd like to be able to hold an array of these objects, all of which have the same template parameter `T` but may be different classes. It seems like I cannot use neither plain inheritence nor type erasue (at least the way I know it) because the function is a template. Is there a good way to do this? Or am I looking for the wrong solution?

Comment: Are the possible types in the array bounded?

Comment: std::variant maybe?

Comment: @Klaus I feel like there should be a better way to do this. with a variant, I'd have to check which type is contaiened at any given moment and then `std::get` it out of the variant, which would be both very inconvenient from a user POV and impose a larger runtime overhead than simply using inheritence (if it was possible in the first place).

Comment: "*which would be both very inconvenient from a user POV and impose a larger runtime overhead than simply using inheritence (if it was possible in the first place).*" There is no *runtime* overhead.

Comment: By using `std::visit` the compiler generates a jump table to the given function for each type which is typically as fast as a vtable jump. From runtime consumption I don't see any problems. There is no need to implement a inheritance monster to get the correct function called via vtable. Especially if templates and runtime polymorphism come into play, std::variant is much more flexible,

Comment: This question has some similar vibes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002943/pure-virtual-method-taking-all-sorts-of-iterators. I wrote a preliminary `any_const_input_iterator_of<T>` there that could potentially be used as the parameter to the function call operator in a regular type-erased interface for these classes. If your set of functor classes is known up front, though, I would definitely go with the approach of `variant<match<T>, other_match<T>, third_match<T>>` for all your `match`-like classes. You can also hide the variant behind a convenient interface that `visit`s internally.

Comment: @chris this is a good idea, I'll give it a go. though the any_iterator looks interesting as well, I don't think it's a fit for my case compared to a variant as was suggested.

Comment: @aradarbel10, Here's a quick mock-up of what I was thinking with the polymorphic iterator: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rKGq3seM6. The new part is at the bottom where there's a hastily put-together `any_match_of<T>` using the same type erasure technique as the iterator, plus a couple hacky `const` tweaks to the starting code. The `main` function is probably the point of interest for what I was picturing.

Answer (score 0):

@chris comment is great, if my understanding is correct, basically it add an extra layer of abstraction on your IterT thus make the match function able to be erased(and then be stored in some container)

As you said:

> I'd like to be able to hold an array of these objects, all of which have the same template parameter T but may be different classes.

So it seems that we must add a new abstraction layer to work with this constraint, chris's perspective is to start with the IterT. And i'd like to provide a new perspective stolen from `ThreadExecutor`.

Generally almost all `ThreadExecutor` have such interface:

```cpp
std::future<R> execute(Func&& f, Args&&... args);
```

Just like your situation, the args and return type are both template parameter, and `ThreadExecutor` also need to store these user pass task in a container. Basically, `ThreadExecutor` handle this by wrapping the user pass task inside a `packaged_task` to erase the arg type, then wrap the `packaged_task` inside a function wrapper or something to erase the return type.

This is a very naive code snippet, which directly use value capture and so on, but i think it can express the basic idea.

```cpp
struct Container{
    template<typename IterT>
    void add(match<IterT> func, IterT iter){
        store_.push_back(std::function([=](){
            std::packaged_task([=](){
                return func(iter);
            })();
        }));
    }

    std::vector<std::function<void()>> store_;
};
```